# How to update the git dasho map files

Tags: git

After deleting a remote branch with the following command

```
git push origin --delete <remote_branch_name>
```

I get the following using the command **`git branch -vv`**

```
...
local_branch_name SHA-1 [origin/remote_branch_name: gone] Update the dasho map files
...
```

What does it means "Update the dasho map files"? How to do it?
I have tried with **`git fetch origin`** but it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply the message of the commit your branch `local_branch_name` is pointing to.

You don't have to do anything: there is no problem.

You can change your branch to stop tracking the "gone" remote branch `origin/remote_branch_name` with:

```
git branch --unset-upstream local_branch_name
```

Then, the output of `git branch -vv` would be:

```
...
local_branch_name SHA-1 Update the dasho map files
...
```